# How important is pronunciation in spellcasting?

Tags: harry-potter

How important is the actual pronunciation of magic words in *Harry Potter*? To that end, what if there was a deaf-mute Wizard, or a wizard who had his throat ripped out by a werewolf? Or if you had a heavy accent or lisp? Clearly there are foreign wizards, do they have their own spells or translations? Is a Chinese wizard expected to say *Evatacavra*? Also, if it is just the intent of the spell, why would anyone ever say a spell out loud? It's unstrategic.

Comment: [From the first movie... A well known scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAQBzjE-kvI&feature=youtu.be&t=26s)

Comment: [And, of course, when it's pronounced wrong...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAQBzjE-kvI&feature=youtu.be&t=1m15s)

Answer (score 13):

Pronunciation is **extremely** important in spell casting. That is covered during the Wingardium Leviosa class, in the first book.

Professor Flitwick himself tells the students to be extra careful when pronouncing the spell, and he mentions the example of wizard who got badly injured from wrongly pronouncing the spell he wanted to cast.

A while later, Hermione points out how Ron's spell is being ineffective due to his mispronunciation.

> “Wingardium Leviosa!” he shouted, waving his long arms like a windmill. “You’re saying it wrong,” Harry heard Hermione snap. “It’s Wing-gar-dium Levi-o-sa, make the ‘gar’ nice and long.” “You do it, then, if you’re so clever,” Ron snarled.”

(As rightly stated above by Cearon O'Flynn)

And even sometime after that we see a practical example of Professor Flitwick's story, when Seamus feather's burst into flames (scene that was also in the movie).

Comment: Great answer, +1, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Also from the movie: Hermione tells Ron "It's levi-Oh-sa, not levio-Sah". (excuse my self-interpreted pronunciations)

Comment: Proper pronunciation is essential only for newbies. Advanced wizards can cast spells silently.

Comment: @Endgame - Ah, but presumably that means you have to pronounce it right when you *think* the name of the spell.

Answer (score 11):

### Essential (with a caveat)

In the first book, Professor Flitwick explicitly says that  speaking the right words is essential for the spell to function correctly. Indeed, major errors, such as changing an entire phoneme, can have disastrous consequences:

> "And saying the magic words properly is very important, too -- never
> forget Wizard Baruffio, who said 's' instead of 'f' and found himself
> on the floor with a buffalo on his chest."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*

If someone were rendering incapable of uttering a spell correctly, they would also be incapable of using that spell. At worst, it would produce some alternate effect, as indicated in the previous quotation. At best, the spell would simply fail, as seen when Neville tried to perform magic with a broken nose:

> “*STUBEFY!*” shouted Neville, wheeling around and waving Hermione’s wand
> at the oncoming Death Eaters. “*STUBEFY*, *STUBEFY!*”
>
> But nothing happened — one of the Death Eaters shot their own Stunning
> Spell at Neville; it missed him by inches.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

**The caveat: talented witches and wizards can perform nonverbal spells.**

A sufficiently skilled spellcaster can use any incantation nonverbally. Some are even specifically nonverbal, such as *Levicorpus*. So someone who had had their throat ripped out by a werewolf (for example) could still learn to use any spell, but with more difficulty. It is likely, however, that particularly hard spells would be of reduced effectiveness:

> She winced slightly and put a hand to her ribs. The curse Dolohov had
> used on her, though **less effective than it would have been had he been
> able to say the incantation aloud**, had nevertheless caused, in Madam
> Pomfrey’s words, “quite enough damage to be going on with.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

Comment: Good examples. You have my +1

Comment: Yes. You *must* annunciate. The age old spell *The weather is beautiful, wish you were her(e)* has broken up more relationships than the chastity charms that guard the girls dormatories.

Answer (score 5):

Yes the pronunciation is very important

For example in The Philospohers Stone Ron is saying Wingardium Leviosa incorrectly and cannot get the spell to work:

> “Wingardium Leviosa!” he shouted, waving his long arms like a
>   windmill. “You’re saying it wrong,” Harry heard Hermione snap. “It’s
>   Wing-gar-dium Levi-o-sa, make the ‘gar’ nice and long.” “You do it,
>   then, if you’re so clever,” Ron snarled.”

Comment: Not to mention "diagonally" as opposed to "Diagon Alley"

Comment: When i was reading the book to my children my other half was listening too and it took me a little while to get across to her why i was saying diagonally and not Diagon Alley... the kids got it :|

Comment: another instance is when i believe nevell has a bloody noise and cant properly cast any spells because he cant speak properly. Im thinking this is from Order of the Phoenix in the ministry scene. However at the same time, we know that nonverbal spells no longer really have pronunciation issue, at this point its more on the intent of the spell, where as at a young age using verbally, the verbal incantation ties together with the intent of the user more, since the young witch and wizard have less control, or will power to put into their magic, IMO.

Comment: @WadCheber I'm not meaning to be disrespectful or anything. I just feel like writing another answer which will have the exact information this one has + my one paragraph addendum isn't wise. I am not, in any way, changing the nature of this question. Indeed I am only adding a piece of information which is regarded on the very part that is _mentioned_ in this answer.

Comment: @AugustoQ - The proper way to do that is by adding a comment, not changing the answer.

Comment: @AugustoQ I realize you are trying to help, and I appreciate that.  I'm just trying to help you do it the right way.

Comment: @WadCheber I realise that as well, and I appreciate it too. I guess I took "changing the answer" as literally changing the meaning of the answer (as to change what he's written already) in order to make use of the likes he has already gotten. Oh well

Comment: @WadCheber I will leave a comment and am writing a new answer as well :)

Comment: @AugustoQ - If the answer is as good as the edits you've been making, I will give you the first upvote.

Comment: @WadCheber thank you for the help, as you can probably see, I am new to the website, so that means a good deal to me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a combination of wand movement (discussed during DA sessions and lessons such as Wingardium Leviosa), intention and knowledge of the spell's incantation and finally the pronunciation of the incantation. I imagine non-verbal spells require a version of the incantation in one's mind, rather than just thinking "levitate that feather!"
It would seem that as the incantation can be dropped, it is the least important and pronunciation is not that essential.
However it is easier to say a spell as well as wand movement and intention, so presumably the less talented or experienced you are, the more it matters. Also, the relationship between wand and wizard would be less well-developed and instructions would need to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In *Order of the Phoenix* we see a case where the mispronunciation of the incantation caused someone's clothes to be set on fire, so pronunciation clearly matters:

> "Oh no," said Cho rather wildly as he approached. "Expelliarmious! I mean, Expellimellius! I — oh, sorry, Marietta!"
>
> Her curly-haired friend’s sleeve had caught fire; Marietta extinguished it with her own wand and glared at Harry as though it was his fault.

Comment: That's rather vocabulary than pronunciation, Expellimellius is entirely different from Expelliarmus

Comment: @Jenayah You might be right. I don't know where the line is between a mispronunciation of a word and an entirely different word.

Comment: My opinion only, but "mispronunciation" would be the same spelling, but with a different emphasis (_"It's Leviooosa, not Leviosaaaa"_), different world begins when you start adding/modifying syllables.

Comment: @Jenayah What about the example of "Wizard Baruffio who said 's' instead of 'f'"? Or Neville's "Stubefy" instead of "Stupefy"?

Comment: Different words in my book (pun... half intended :P )

Comment: @Jenayah (For the record, "Leviooosa" and "Leviosaaaa" are spelled differently.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that pronunciation is important.  But there are other languages, not to mention those who were very capable of silent casting.  To assume that everyone must use the Latin (?) words for these spells is a bit silly as there were other schools of magic (Beauxbatons and Durmstrang officially mentioned) in the world.

Comment: It doesn't seem at all silly that French wizards would cast spells in "Latin" (no sillier than English wizards, anyway). Durmstrang is a fair point though

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan Perry already pointed out one answer with the story when Harry used Floo Powder to go to Diagon Alley and said "diagonal" we see "critical or else it will be a problem"

Comment: I don't understand that last part, could you [edit] your answer to make it clearer?